# I'm getting 404 error once I select programCategory. What i want is when I clicks programCategory all courses should display under that category

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, entity-framework-6, code-first

this question is related with my previous question.

[How to search and load data in database by using a string keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31835598/how-to-search-and-load-data-in-database-by-using-a-string-keyword)

This is index method in controller.

```
    public ActionResult Index(string crsCtgry)
    {
        var viewModel = new DisplayCourseIndexData();

        viewModel.ProgramCategory = db.ProgramCategoriess;
        if (crsCtgry != null)
        {
            viewModel.CourseCategories = db.CourseCategories.Where(n => n.courseField == crsCtgry).Select(n => n).ToList();
        }
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

This is the Razer-View

```
<div class="col-sm-4 page-sidebar">
                    <aside>
                        <div class="widget sidebar-widget white-container links-widget">
                            <br>
                            <div class="title-lines">
                                <h4 class="m0" style="color:deepskyblue">Course List</h4>
                            </div>
                            @foreach (var item in Model.ProgramCategory)
                            {
                                <ul class="ullist">
                                    <li>
                                        @Html.ActionLink(item.courseCategory, "Details", new { id = item.courseCategory }, new { @class = "" })
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </aside>
                </div>




                <div class="col-sm-4 page-content">
                    <div class="white-container mb0">

                        @if (Model.CourseCategories != null)
                        {
                            <h3>Courses Taught by Selected Instructor</h3>
                            <table class="table">
                                <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>Number</th>
                                    <th>Title</th>
                                    <th>Department</th>
                                </tr>

                                @foreach (var item in Model.CourseCategories)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            @item.courseSubject
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @item.courseName
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                }

                            </table>
                        }

                    </div>
                </div>
```

And this is the viewModel class

```
 public class DisplayCourseIndexData
    {
        public IEnumerable<CourseCategory> CourseCategories { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ProgramCategories> ProgramCategory { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: The link is to an action method called `Details` on that controller.  Does such an action method exist?  It's not shown in the question.

Comment: I think that Details should replace with "Index" Because the results again display in same view. i  change that in to Index, but still im getting 404 error @David

Comment: How is everything going to display in the same view?  Maybe you want the details to "expand" when you click an item?  In that case you wouldn't want to use action links, you'd probably want to use a non-link HTML element and show/hide the details with JavaScript.  As for the 404 error, what is the *actual link* you're trying to go to and does it map to a route in your controller?  If not, then that's a 404 error.  Any link to your application needs to be handled in some way.

Comment: When i click on it I want get all courses saved under selected category. actually its like a search keyword. Program categories are in the left side of the page, when i click category result need to show in right side(pannel). @David

Comment: Since you're not explicitly returning a 404 anywhere in your action, the only place a 404 could be generated is in the routing layer. In other words,  this has nothing to do with your model, view, etc. You might consider posting the URL you're attempting to access and the contents of your `RouteConfig.cs` file. Otherwise, we're kind of powerless to help you.

Comment: Finally I made it.
 @Html.ActionLink(item.courseCategory, "Index", new { crsCtgry = item.courseCategory }, new { @class = "" })

I passed incorrect method name and incorrect parameter name. now its working. Thanks all who trying to help me. Highly appreciated :)